# who loaded my kernel modules?

Tags: gentoo, kernel-modules

I have compiled a kernel with some modules, for example the `ath9k` for my wireless card. I don't have anything in the autoload configuration (i.e my file `/etc/modules.autoload.d/kernel-2.6` is empty). However, `lsmod` still shows that the module has been loaded. I also notice that when I compile filesystem support as modules (reiserfs, jfs, xfs etc.) they also get autoloaded.

Who is doing this? Can and should I disable it? I am using Gentoo.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Udev loads modules automatically depending on what kind of hardware it finds. You can "blacklist" modules in order to stop them being autoloaded as described in the [Gentoo udev guide](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/udev-guide.xml).

Comment: so, why did the reiserfs, jfs and xfs get loaded too? I don't have any of those?

Comment: I suppose udev loads those as well to be able to mount (external) harddrives. I'm not on a Gentoo box right now, but you could just try adding the filesystem drivers to the blacklist for modules and see if they stay unloaded.

Comment: They could also have been loaded by initrd's `linuxrc` script.